# Closing all WebSocket sessions using Spring GraphQL

Tags: spring, websocket, graphql

I'm working on a Spring GraphQL (newest spring-boot-starter-graphql) project and I'm using WebSocket to establish subscriptions. However, I'm having trouble finding a way to close all WebSocket sessions programmatically.

I've looked into the documentation and searched for examples, but I couldn't find a clear solution specific to Spring GraphQL. Most of the resources I found were related to general WebSocket implementations or STOMP.

Framework has a handler (GraphQlWebSocketHandler#WebMvcSessionInfo) that wraps WebSocketSession and places it in an internal sessionInfoMap that is not shared externally.

I want to make sure that all active sessions are properly terminated when a specific event occurs.
Any help or code examples demonstrating the approach would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by extending GraphQlWebSocketHandler and collecting web socket sessions in bean collection.

```
@Component
class CustomGraphqlWebSocketHandler extends GraphQlWebSocketHandler {

    private final Collection<WebSocketSession> sessions;

    CustomGraphqlWebSocketHandler(WebGraphQlHandler graphQlHandler, HttpMessageConverter<?> mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter,
                                  Collection<WebSocketSession> sessions) {
        super(graphQlHandler, mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        this.sessions = sessions;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) {
        sessions.add(session);
        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus closeStatus) {
        sessions.remove(session);
        super.afterConnectionClosed(session, closeStatus);
    }
}
```